# My steering wheel whines but only after sitting in the sun

Tags: steering-wheel

I have a 2014 Toyota Venza. So I noticed that as I’m driving home from work that after a while, my steering wheel would begin to make whining noises when I turn. Power-steering is still working and everything else seems fine, though the whining is also vibrating my gas pedal so it can’t just be a wheel issue. The problem strangely goes away the next morning, and my car becomes completely fine. I’ve been thinking it has something to do with the days being so hot and my car being out in the sun and heating up.

Comment: Does this just happen when you are running the AC? If you're not sure, that would be something to check. Usually when it's quite hot we run AC, so I think that's worth trying to isolate.

Comment: That could be simply a squeaking belt. Verify the belts tensions and condition, it might need replacement. Also a recording of the noise could help a lot understanding what you mean by "whining".

Comment: Have you checked the power steering fluid level?